# Given an m x n matrix of 0s and 1s, if an element is 0, set its entire row and column to 0

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures

Given an m x n matrix of 0s and 1s, if an element is 0, set its entire row and column to 0

How can we solve this problem without any extra space complexity

Answer (score 1):

Use first row and first column as list of flags for marking corresponding column and row respectively. So in total, there would be `m+n-1` flags available to you for `mxn` matrix, only one ***extra*** flag would be needed to mark `1st` row or `1st` column (its upon programmer to choose, doesn't make difference though).

```
[C0/R0] C1 C2 ... Cn-1
  R1      
  R2
   .
  Rm-1

Take one extra flag for [R0/C0].
```

Then traverse through the matrix, marking the flags if any of element in the column or row is 0.

Then once you finish traversing, use those flags to decide which column or row would be filled with all 0's.

Comment: Wouldn't we lose the information of 0's and 1's in first row/column?

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja The final modified matrix would anyway require each of those elements in first column and first row to be zeroed..

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach would be to simply iterate the whole matrix:

```
for i in 1 to number of rows
 for j in 1 to number of columns
   if n(i,j) == 0:
     for all n(i, 1 to number of columns): set to 0
     for all n(1 to number of rows, j): set to 0
```

This doesn't require any additional space besides the the two loop counters. Of course, it is O(scary) regarding performance, but you didn't ask about that.

In order to enhance performance, you could collect all row and column indexes that contain 1; and zero-ize them just once; but that would mean: allocating space for those indexes.

Answer (score 0):

- Reduce the space used to O(1) by using boolean variables (and not boolean array)
- check if first row & column are zero. If yes, set the corresponding boolean variables: `rowZero` and `colZero`
- iterate through the remaining rows & columns and mark them as zero wherever applicable
- if the first row/column is not zero, then use the methods to mark them as zero

```cs
        public static void ZeroMatrixResultBitVector(int[][] matrix)
        {
            bool rowZero = false;
            bool colZero = false;

            // check if first row has zero
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++)
            {
                if (matrix[i][0] == 0)
                {
                    colZero = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // check if first column is zero
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].Length; j++)
            {
                if (matrix[0][j] == 0)
                {
                    rowZero = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //if the above hasn't been true then we will update the first column/row later
            for (int i = 1; i < matrix.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < matrix[0].Length; j++)
                {
                    if (matrix[i][j] == 0)
                    {
                        matrix[i][0] = 0;
                        matrix[0][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            //nullify all row related records
            for (int i = 1; i < matrix.Length; i++)
            {
                if (matrix[i][0] == 0)
                {
                    nullifyRow(matrix, i);
                }
            }

            //nullify all column related records
            for (int j = 1; j < matrix[0].Length; j++)
            {
                if (matrix[0][j] == 0)
                {
                    nullifyColumn(matrix, j);
                }
            }

            if (rowZero)
            {
                nullifyRow(matrix, 0);
            }

            if (colZero)
            {
                nullifyColumn(matrix, 0);
            }

        }
```

Function to nullify Rows:

```cs
        private static void nullifyRow(int[][] matrix, int row)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].Length; j++)
            {
                matrix[row][j] = 0;
            }
        }
```

Function to nullify column:

```cs
        private static void nullifyColumn(int[][] matrix, int column)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix[0].Length; i++)
            {
                matrix[i][column] = 0;
            }
        }
```